# The L^2-product of two weakly converging functions

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\phi_k\rightharpoonup \phi$ and $\xi_k \rightharpoonup \xi$ both in $L^2$. Is it possible to conclude the following?
\begin{equation}
\langle \phi_k,\xi_k\rangle_{L^2} \rightarrow \langle \phi,\xi\rangle_{L^2}
\end{equation}

Comment: No. Take $\phi_k = \xi_k$. Then you want $||\phi_k|| \to ||\phi||$, which might not hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If $\{e_n\}$ is orthonormal then $e_n \to 0$ weakly but $\langle e_n,e_n \rangle$ does not tend to $0$.